# How about we blacklist [number]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-blacklist

The [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) tag made a horrible comeback today with already two questions. I feel this is a zombie tag which keeps coming as we keep killing it. And unlike some historical figures which are said to have rose from the dead, this tag is not going to bring peace and harmony to the world.

So how about we make a request to blacklist it?

---

(Dec. 30, 2013) I just removed [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) from a post. Are we blacklisting this or not?

(Feb. 3, 2016) I just removed [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) from another two posts. I was on my way to post a request to blacklist this tag, but then I saw that I already made that request two and a half years ago!

Comment: Frankenstein's monster? I didn't think it was historic.

Comment: @Andres: The Monster wasn't alive before. It was a brand new creation from parts of dead people.

Comment: I re-tagged the two questions using the [tag:number] tag.

Comment: I don't know what to consider.  Which post did you remove [tag:number] from?

Comment: @MJD: Hm. I can't find it in my activity so the OP must have deleted it. I'll check when I am home, maybe I can find it in the history of my desk computer.

Comment: It reappeared and was removed also in [September 2014](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2014/9/24). (I guess this counts as a supporting evidence showing that this problematic tag keeps popping up again and again.) And probably several more times, but it is difficult to find such things.

Comment: I've pinged somebody who can edit the blacklist. Now it's a matter of waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon request, the tag [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) (as well as the plural form) has been blacklisted today.

Comment: Huzzah! It only took two and a half years and several complaints!

Comment: It's all a question of the right timing.

Answer (score 27):

**Please do not vote down this answer.**

Please vote this up if you think that blacklisting the [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) tag is a **good idea**.

Answer (score -1):

**Please do not vote down this answer.**

Please vote this up if you think that blacklisting the [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) is **not a good idea**.

Comment: What happens if I upvote both?

Comment: @Arkamis, every time you vote contradictory poll answers a child starves to death in Africa.

Comment: Yes but are those events correlated?

Comment: The link between these events has not been sufficiently studied in modern science because it accounts as experimentation in human beings and has severe ethical issues.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you could have handled that with a single answer...Unless you ask a third one for those who have no opinion. Interesting rep trick ;). I'm kidding.

Comment: @julien: You should know that meta doesn't give any reputation!

Comment: Didn't you notice that I make a lot of lousy comments? Let me reformulate: interesting badge trick ;).

Comment: @julien: You get badges for CW answers, except Enlightened, which you don't get for self answers anyway.

Comment: Good: now I know how badges and rep work on meta...

Comment: @julien: CW badges are awarded on the main as well. There is no rep on meta. In fact there used to be a "rep" page where you could see what posts of your were recently voted, but they removed that for some reason. Meta never contributed to the actual reputation though. Only a couple of badges (Convention and Quorum).

Comment: Ok, thanks for all that. Here is what I was thinking about. When I'm on meta, if I click on my name, I access my profile. I see my main rep. But badges I earned from Q/A on meta only, a different count. Now still on meta, if I click on your name and access your profile, I see you have 34 badges, all earned I assume from Q/A on meta exclusively. As opposed to your 11 badges on main. For instance, you just earned a nice answer badge for your answer one above. Got you!

Comment: @julien: Yes. Badges on meta are different, and it's a whole other game here. Especially because votes carry no reputation. But also because there are far less active threads on meta, so it's easier to gather votes for more than an hour before the thread disappears into the archives known as "not the front page" :-)

Comment: "Please do not vote down this answer." ... at score -1. Oh well.

Comment: @quid: Maybe some people don't know English that well... :)